# How to Make Timeline View using RecylerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am making a `view` which is similar to Timeline `View` using `Recylerview` 
[Recylerview Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VndD.jpg)

see this image for view reference. I want to hide the zero position up line and last position down line and all the item get connected to the line
the problem i am facing i am not getting connected line when the size of list get more than 5 in between the both lines get hide

**Here is my code what i tried**

```html
package com.zkteco.zktime.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.zkteco.zktime.Model.PunchModel;
import com.zkteco.zktime.MyRequest.LeaveDetailsActivity;
import com.zkteco.zktime.MyRequest.RequestAdapter;
import com.zkteco.zktime.MyRequest.RequestModel;
import com.zkteco.zktime.R;

import java.util.List;

public class PunchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PunchAdapter.PunchViewHolder> {

    private List<PunchModel> punchModelList;
    Context context;




    public PunchAdapter(Context context,List<PunchModel> punchModelList) {
        this.punchModelList = punchModelList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public PunchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.punch_list_row, parent, false);

        return new PunchViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PunchViewHolder holder, int position) {
        PunchModel punchModel = punchModelList.get(position);
        holder.punch_time.setText(punchModel.getTime());
        holder.check_status.setText(punchModel.getCheck());
        holder.punch_address.setText(punchModel.getAddress());

        if (position == 0){
            holder.view_up.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if (punchModelList.size() -1 >= 2 && punchModelList.size() > 1){
                holder.view_down.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          //  }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return punchModelList.size();
    }




    public class PunchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView punch_time;
        TextView check_status;
        TextView punch_address;
        View view_up;
        View view_down;


        public PunchViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            punch_time = view.findViewById(R.id.punch_time);
            check_status = view.findViewById(R.id.check_status);
            punch_address = view.findViewById(R.id.punch_address);
            view_up = view.findViewById(R.id.view_up);
            view_down = view.findViewById(R.id.view_down);



        }




    }
}
```